# Como determinar o índice de elementos de uma lista noutra

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trabalho com *python 2.7*. Considerando as seguintes:

```
S_names=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
S_values=[1,3,4,2,5,8,10]
other=["Z","W","B","S","A","E","X","T","D","G","L","C","F"]
```

Preciso de encontrar em que posição de `other` se encontram os elementos de `S_names`. Para obter a lista de índices dos elementos de `S_names` em `other`, resultando na lista `Result`:

```
Result=[4,2,11,8,5,12,9]
```

Tentei trabalhar com dicionários fazendo o seguinte:

```
def indicesDeElementoNaLista_s(elementoProcurado, lista):
    return [i for (i, elemento) in lista if elemento == elementoProcurado]

def elementosNasPosicoes_s(lista, posicoes):
    return [lista[i] for i in posicoes]

carg={}
for elemento in S_names:
    posicoes=indicesDeElementoNaLista_s(elemento,other)
    elementosCorrespondentes=elementosNasPosicoes_s(S_values,posicoes)
    cargas_sub[elemento]=elementosCorrespondentes_s
```

Mas obtive diversos erros e não entendo o que está errado...
Como posso contornar esta situação?

Comment: Qual relação estás querendo fazer com a lista S_values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obter o Result que você deseja, podes fazer da seguinte forma:

```
>>> S_names = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
>>> S_values =[1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 8, 10]
>>> other = ["Z", "W", "B", "S", "A", "E", "X", "T", "D", "G", "L", "C", "F"]
>>> 
>>> Result = [other.index(i) for i in S_names if i in other]
>>> print(Result)
[4, 2, 11, 8, 5, 12, 9]
```

Porém, isso relaciona apenas as listas S_names e other. Vendo o restante do seu código, imagino que queiras um dicionário com o nome e posição dos itens que repetem na lista 'other' e nas posições que repetem na lista S_values. Se for isso, podes fazer assim:

```
>>> posicoes = [other.index(i) for i in S_names if i in other]
>>> print(posicoes)
[4, 2, 11, 8, 5, 12, 9]
>>>
>>> elementosCorrespondentes = [S_values[i] for i in range(len(S_values)) if S_values[i] == posicoes[i]]
>>> print(elementosCorrespondentes)
[5]
>>>
>>> carg = {S_names[i]:i for i in elementosCorrespondentes}
>>> print(carg)
{'F': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá! vê se isso te ajuda:

```
S_names=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
S_values=[1,3,4,2,5,8,10]
other=["Z","W","B","S","A","E","X","T","D","G","L","C","F"]

result = []
for name in S_names:
    result.append(other.index(name))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer assim:

```
for name in S_names:
    for x in other:
        if name == x:
            Result.append(other.index(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai uma maneira cujo a variável final vai armazenar todas a letras presentes de S_names presentes em other e respetivo index (key):

```
results = []
for i in other:
    if i in S_names:
        print i+ ' - ' +str(other.index(i))
        results.append({'letter': i, 'index': other.index(i)})
print results

# Resultados: [{'index': 2, 'letter': 'B'}, {'index': 4, 'letter': 'A'}, {'index': 5, 'letter': 'E'}, {'index': 8, 'letter': 'D'}, {'index': 9, 'letter': 'G'}, {'index': 11, 'letter': 'C'}, {'index': 12, 'letter': 'F'}]
```

Fazendo com list compreension:

```
results = [{'letter':i, 'index':other.index(i)} for i in other if i in S_names]
print results

# Resultados: [{'index': 2, 'letter': 'B'}, {'index': 4, 'letter': 'A'}, {'index': 5, 'letter': 'E'}, {'index': 8, 'letter': 'D'}, {'index': 9, 'letter': 'G'}, {'index': 11, 'letter': 'C'}, {'index': 12, 'letter': 'F'}]
```

Não percebi bem onde entram aí os S_values, mas vou jogar com o que eu penso você quer acerca de S_values:

Caso que queira ver se os indices em other das letras de S_names estão na lista de S_values:

```
results = [{'letter':i, 'index':other.index(i)} for i in other if i in S_names and other.index(i) in S_values]
print results

# Resultados: [{'index': 2, 'letter': 'B'}, {'index': 4, 'letter': 'A'}, {'index': 5, 'letter': 'E'}, {'index': 8, 'letter': 'D'}]
```

Ciclo for equivalente a isto:

```
results = []
for i in other:
    if i in S_names and other.index(i) in S_values:
        results.append({'letter': i, 'index': other.index(i)})
print results

# Resultados: [{'index': 2, 'letter': 'B'}, {'index': 4, 'letter': 'A'}, {'index': 5, 'letter': 'E'}, {'index': 8, 'letter': 'D'}]
```